# Generating an integer divisible by 90 with math.random()

Tags: random, lua

Is it possible to make `math.random()` return only numbers divisible by 90?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function random_90(lower, upper)
    return math.random(math.ceil(lower/90), math.floor(upper/90))*90
end

print(random_90(100, 1000))
```

Remember to call `math.randomseed()` **once** before using `math.random()`. And it's better to call `math.random()` several times before using it for real because in some implementations, the first few numbers may not look that random.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
math.random(); math.random(); math.random();
```

Comment: I think you need `math.random(math.ceil(lower/90),math.floor(upper/90))*90` because there is no integer division in Lua.

Comment: @lhf Fixed now. I thought about that so I tested the code on my machine(Lua5.1) before posting it. It(the old code) works. And I was just checking with the source code, looks like when `math.random` gets one or two arguments, in Lua 5.1 it uses `int`, but in Lua 5.2, it uses `lua_Number`. That's a trivial difference that I did not know.

Answer (score 4):

You could just generate any random integer and multiply it by 90.

I've never used Lua, but math.random(int x, int y) will generate a random integer between x and y.  Multiply that by 90.  The result will be just as random as any other number that gets generated.